# How can I use full join to all two unique combinations of data sets from a list having 3 data sets?

Tags: r

I have a list a() having 3 data sets a[[1]], a[[2]], a[[3]]. Now I want to apply full_join on two unique combinations of these data sets i.e. I want to join a[[1]] with a[[2]], a[[2]] with a[[3]] and a[[3]] with a[[1]]. So the new list will contain 3 joined data sets. And I want to apply it for more than 3 data sets i.e. I want to make it generic. How can I do this?

I was trying the below code. But it is creating a list b() with 2 data sets while I want 3 joined data sets.

```r
b <- list()

for (i in 1:length(a)){
  for(j in 1:length(a)){
    if( i < j) {
      b[[i]] <- full_join(a[[i]], b[[j]], by = 'x')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check with `combn`  i.e `combn(a, 3, FUN = function(x)...)` and here instead of full_join directly on two datasets, use `reduce(listelements, full_join, by = 'x')`

Comment: Is it with every combination (as in @akrun's suggestion for `combn`), or just all-neighbors? If the latter, perhaps something like `Map(dplyr::full_join, a[c(1,2,3)], a[c(2,3,1)])` might suffice, and those vectors are easy enough to generate for neighbor sequencing.